# Generator decorator in Python

Tags: python, generator, decorator

[PEP343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) defines a “Generator Decorator,” and says “A robust implementation of this decorator will be made part of the standard library.”  Where is this in the standard library?  Does anyone use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's here: [`contextlib.contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).  I never used it.

Comment: Because you never implemented a simple context manager, I suppose?

Comment: @delnan: Except for some experimentation, I never implemented one, right :)